# yolov8 doesn´t initiate freezes after train: scanning

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, yolov8, ultralytics

I am trying to get `yolo` to use my `gpu`, and I have gotten it to start, but then it reaches the stage of scanning the train and afterwards val images, but just freezes after doing the train ones.

This is the output and where it stops:

```
Ultralytics YOLOv8.1.6  Python-3.11.7 torch-2.1.2+cu121 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER, 12281MiB)
    engine\trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8s.yaml, data=path_n_class.yaml, epochs=300, time=None, patience=50, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=0, workers=8, project=None, name=train, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs\detect\train
    Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=1

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       928  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 32, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1     29056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  4                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]           
  5                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  6                  -1  2    788480  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1   1180672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [256, 512, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1   1838080  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [512, 512, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    656896  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [512, 512, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    591360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [768, 256, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 15                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]                 
 16                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    590336  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [256, 256, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 21                  -1  1   1969152  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [768, 512, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1   2116435  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [1, [128, 256, 512]]          
YOLOv8s summary: 225 layers, 11135987 parameters, 11135971 gradients, 28.6 GFLOPs

Freezing layer 'model.22.dfl.conv.weight'
AMP: running Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP) checks with YOLOv8n...
Downloading https://github.com/ultralytics/assets/releases/download/v8.1.0/yolov8n.pt to 'yolov8n.pt'...
100%|██████████| 6.23M/6.23M [00:00<00:00, 7.51MB/s]
AMP: checks passed ✅
train: Scanning C:\Users\lichs\Desktop\pj\8nano100\training\datasets\data\labels\train.cache... 762 images, 204 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 762/762 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

I have tried to run the same code just removing the device=0 argument so it goes back to using the cpu, but it still does the same.